# How can a variable in C++be named a function call?

Tags: c++, allegro

While going through some allegro tutorials I found an odd call.

```
int al_init();
```

The function `al_init()` initializes allegro so that the allegro functions can be used. What is with the `int al_init();` line? If I change this line of the code to exclude `int` it works the same, but if I take out the line altogether it does not work. What is this line doing? The only thing I can imagine is that it creates an integer and assigns it the return value of the `al_init()` function, with that likely being `-1` for failure and `0` for success etc. But if that is what this is doing, then how can you even check the return value?

Comment: Sure looks like a function prototype/declaration instead of a function call or definition to me.

Comment: How does it fail to work? I bet it fails to compile, right?

Comment: `al_init()` is a macro that expands to `al_install_system(ALLEGRO_VERSION_INT, atexit)`. If you include the Allegro headers properly there's no need to include that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C/C++ there are function declarations and function definitions:

**Declarations** look like these:

```
int a_function();
void another_function();
double yet_another_function();
```

Explanation:

- The identifier before the function name (e.g. `int`, `void`, `double`) describes the type of value returned by the function.
- If you do not specify one, it defaults to `int` (which is why it works when you remove `int` from `int al_init()`, but not when you remove the declaration altogether)
- `void` means it's not supposed to return a value (even though technically it can, but that's for rarer cases)

**Definitions** look like these:

```
int a_function() {
    std::cout << "hello world!";
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    return (x + y);
}
```

Notice the difference:

- Declarations end with `;`
- Definitions are followed by a block of code enclosed by braces: `{` and `}`, but no `;`!
- In some cases, you do not need to declare a function. If it's at a point in the code where the definition has already been seen, the definition can substitute for the declaration (this leads us to the next point...)
- The purpose of declaration is to tell the program that, for example, there is a function named `a_function`, it expects no arguments, and it returns a value of type `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you aren't looking at the function declaration?

Answer (score 1):

According to C's syntactic rules, a prototype is defined as:

`<return-type> function-name (param1, param2, ..);`

And a function call is defined as:

`function-name(param1, param2,...);`. So its obviously defining a function prototype and NOT calling the function.

### C89 and previous rules were:

With the above rule, another rule was:
For implicit integer return type, the prototype was suppose to be defined **outside** of any executable function code. If it was inside of a function, it would be called a function-call and not function-prototype-definition.

---

That aside, lets start with the question:

> While going through some allegro tutorials I found an odd call. `int
>   al_init();`

That's incorrect, it looks like a function prototype or declaration

> The function al_init() initializes allegro so that the allegro
>   functions can be used. What is with the int al_init(); line? If I
>   change this line of the code to exclude int it works the same, but if
>   I take out the line altogether it does not work.

What does not work? Stops to compile? That would be obvious because it will not be able to find `al_init()` function. Also the reason it works without the "int" is because its implicitly assumed to return an integer.

> What is this line doing?

Its telling the compiler that `al_init()` library function is defined elsewhere, typically in a `.lib` or `.a` or `.dll`, and you would want to use it in your program.

> The only thing I can imagine is that it creates an integer and assigns
>   it the return value of the al_init() function,

Absolutely incorrect interpretation of code, it does not create any integer, nor assigns any value to it.

> with that likely being -1 for failure and 0 for success etc. But if
>   that is what this is doing, then how can you even check the return
>   value?

Since you want to know what that function returned, you could do this while an actual call to al_init():

`int retval = al_init();`
`printf("al_init() returned %d",retval);`

Comment: You forgot one important detail. The 'default' return type is 'int' if none is specified.

Comment: @Omnifarious not since C99 IIRC

Comment: Well, yeah. :-) But that fact does explain why he or she can remove the `int` and have it still work.